Boot Pixel 8 with AOSP kernel
I am currently using Google Pixel 8. I am trying to download the AOSP kernel, compile it, and flash it into my device.
I followed the instructions from the document below.
https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-pixel-kernels#pixel-gki-kernel-branches. I used the right combinations for my device and was able to compile and build the kernel using Kleaf.
Then, I went to fastboot mode and flashed my device using the commands below.
fastboot flash boot        out/shusky/dist/boot.img
fastboot flash dtbo        out/shusky/dist/dtbo.img
fastboot flash vendor_kernel_boot      out/shusky/dist/vendor_kernel_boot.img
fastboot reboot fastboot
fastboot flash vendor_dlkm out/shusky/dist/vendor_dlkm.img
fastboot flash system_dlkm out/shusky/dist/system_dlkm.img

After these commands, the device was left in fastbootd mode.
What should I do to start my Pixel 8 with the built kernel? It seems when I simply reboot the device, it gets back to its original kernel.
